# generic exception handling and return arg on exception

Tags: python, exception

I am trying to create generic exception handler - for where I can set an arg to return in case of exception, inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129144/generic-exception-handling-in-python-the-right-way).

```
import contextlib


@contextlib.contextmanager
def handler(default):
    try:
        yield
    except Exception as e:
        yield default


def main():
    with handler(0):
        return 1 / 0

    with handler(0):
        return 100 / 0

    with handler(0):
        return 'helllo + 'cheese'
```

But this results in

```
RuntimeError: generator didn't stop after throw()
```

Comment: My python interpreter will not even try to read those syntax errors at the end. (2.7, under gnu)

Comment: @JohanLundberg exactly. What code did you use to reproduce the OP's error?

Comment: You may be able to do this with a custom context manager class, but not this decorator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main conceptual problem is that you try to make the calling function implicitly return a value from within a called function.  To give an example, what you are trying to do is coneptually equivalent to this situation:

```
def f():
    # some magic code here

def g():
    f()
```

And now you want the magic code to make `g()` return some value.  This is never going to work.

Context managers are the wrong tool for this purpose.  Consider using a decorator instead.

Comment: @JonClements: OK, I should be more specific.  By "this is never going to work" I mean "you're never going to make those `with` blocks work in the way you intend".  Of course you can write a wrapper function, but I'd suggest to use a decorator instead.

Comment: I don't think that is correct. The real reason is that this decorator requires a generator that yields only one value. This one yields two values, thus is not "stopped" at the end, as the error says.

Comment: @rikAtee Umm no - pretend that code doesn't exist! The correct way is  pdysigner's answer per your follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13214377/generic-exception-handling-return-value

Comment: @Keith: My answer gives a reason why a context manager can't do what the OP is trying to do.  It indeed does not answer how exactly the error message comes about, since I felt some general advice is more useful here.  Feel free to add your own answer with explanations of the error.