# generic exception handling return value

Tags: python, exception

I am trying to create generic exception handler - for where I can set an arg to return in case of exception.

instead of doing:

```
try:
    ...
except Exception:
    return list()

try:
    ...
except Exception:
    return dict()

try:
    ...
except Exception:
    return str()
```

I would like to create system whereby I have a generic exception handler that returns an arg I provide. e.g,

```
def handler(code, default):
    try:
        code
    except Exception:
        return default

def mains():
    code = <code to execute>
    default = str()
    return handler(code, dafault)
```

but in a more pythonic way

Comment: so you want to have something like "GENERIC_ERROR: problem solved". trial and error type-of problem solving? :-)

Comment: I'm confused as to what exactly you want to create. Could you show how this handler of yours would be used in client code?

Comment: this code will be in functions that should return a list, or another that returns a dict, or another that returns a number. I want to return a default value of an empty list, empty dict, or 0 in case of exceptions in these functions.

Comment: The "pythonic" way would be not doing this and just using a `try..except` directly to make the error handling obvious.

Comment: @millimoose Not necessarily. DRY is a fairly Pythonic concept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple decorator will do this for you.

```
import functools


def catch_wrap(on_err):
    def wrapper(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def inner(*args, **kw):
            try:
                return func(*args, **kw)
            except Exception:
                return on_err
        return inner
    return wrapper
```

A short example:

```
@catch_wrap('SPAM!')
def doer():
    """
    YUP
    """
    1 / 0
    return 'EGGS!'


print doer()
print doer.__doc__
```

Comment: It's probably a good idea to use [`@functools.wraps`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) for code like this.

Comment: @millimoose I don't think that `wraps` would do much extra in this case.

Comment: @pydisigner Oh, I missed that you're already taking steps to preserve `__doc__`. I guess because I'm so used to doing that with `@wraps`. (It does however do more than just `__doc__`)

Comment: @millimoose I just added that :). I don't think that the complexity of `@functools.wrap` is warranted.

Comment: There is a major hole in this; passing bad args will be masked. Time to dig out `inspec.getargspec`...

Comment: @millimoose Yes, but this is a case of simple vs. complex. If DRY applied here, everyone would use the same libs.

Comment: How is `@functools.wraps` complex? It's the best option short of the `@decorator` module.

Comment: WRT to bad args, you could compromise and allow `TypeError`s to escape out.

Comment: @Eric that compromise is probably unacceptable, as `TypeError`s will probably be raised as often in the "real" code as in the wrapper call.

Comment: @Eric: as to `@functools.wraps`, I had to read the actual code for it several times to understand what it did. Simply setting the docstring as I do in this code is much more obvious, as well as faster.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19033/discussion-between-pydsigner-and-eric)

Comment: To the OP: Do you want bad arguments to the wrapped function to be caught? Or do you want an exception raised at that point?