# Catch exceptions in Python 3 like in C#

Tags: c#, python-3.x

I'm better versed in C# than Python.

In C# I can catch all exceptions as default and handle them like showing a error window or write them to a log file.

What about Python? I can't find a default statement, so that I could write all occurred exceptions to a log file and continue with the program.

For example, I want to catch all types of exceptions. In C# it's like this

```
                try
                {
                   do something.....
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(),
                    @"Fehler",
                    MessageBoxButton.OK,
                    MessageBoxImage.Error
                    );
                    return false;
                }
```

It's not necessary to know what kind of exception the program is throwing. How can I do this in Python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generic Exception Handling in Python the "Right Way"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129144/generic-exception-handling-in-python-the-right-way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For default exception handling:

```
except:
    print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info

As ZeroPiraeus point in comment it could be dangerous to use this as it can provide a unwanted behavior in some situations.

Comment: No, you absolutely don't. At a *bare minimum*, you specify `except Exception:` to avoid also catching `SystemExit`, `KeyboardInterrupt` etc., and in almost all cases you avoid that too.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus you don't do what? You can't write this? Or in your opinion he shouldn't?  I can say the same of his code he shouldn't catch general exception in c# but he does. It is not my role to judge his programing style as he could be more superior then me in it. My role is to answer his question.

Comment: Bare `except:` clauses are a very well-known source of hard-to-trace errors, and are universally discouraged by experienced Python programmers. It's irresponsible to answer an unwitting "how do I shoot myself in the foot?" question by showing OP how to disengage the safety, unless you at the very least offer a basic caution against doing so.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus I agree with you but this is true for most languages and probability that someone familiar with c# is not aware of this issue is low. But I will add warning to my answer.

Comment: thanks, for your comments, I learned something about catching all exceptions ;)

Answer (score 0):

From the [python documentation on errors](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) you handle errors in python using `try`/`except`:

```
>>> while True:
...     try:
...         x = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
...         break
...     except ValueError:
...         print("Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again...")
...
```